# Converting TimeSpan to 12 hrs format

Tags: .net, timespan

I am using C#. I need time slots to be inserted in database at the interval of 15 min (from 7am to 10pm). I have used this code:

```
          for (int i = 0; i < 61; i++){
          TimeSpan curtime = new TimeSpan(7, y, 00);
           y=y+15;}
```

But this returns me the slots in 24 hrs i.e from 7:00:00 to 22:00:00. How can I change this?

Comment: Could you explain better what 'format' is expected? And in which datatype on the database are you trying to store the format?

Comment: I am stroing as time in database. it stores as 13:00:00 but i want to store as 01:00:00

Answer (score 1):

A [DateTime column in a database](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2004/datetime-datatype/) (as for SQL Server) is stored as a pair of four byte numeric value where the first 4 bytes are the number of days from  a specific base time (1900/1/1) and the second four bytes are the number of milliseconds from midnight.
So, when you talk about `format`, this is the *display format* of your datetime value and you get it in the way it looks because there is a conversion from the internal format to a string understandable by us. But in the database the datetime is stored always in its internal format

So, to save your time slot, no need to prepare a special format, use simply the current date and increment by 15 minutes at each loop and let the database store it as it deems appropriate

```
 List<DateTime> slots = new List<DateTime>();
 DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013, 7, 26, 7, 0, 0);
 for (int i = 0; i < 61; i++)
 {
      // Save in a list
      slots.Add(dt);

      // Calculate next slot
      dt = dt.AddMinutes(15);
 }
 // Save all the slots to the database
 SaveSlots(slots);
```

To display the DateTime

```
DataTable slots = GetSlotsFromDataBase();
foreach(DataRow r in slots.Rows)
   Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDateTime(r[0]).ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx structure will be helpful , because TimeSpan  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx represents a time interval not a time of day

Else try this out

```
var time = DateTime.ParseExact("17:00", "HH:mm", null).ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use some thing like

```
Datetime.Now.AddMinutes(15)
```

replase DateTime.Now  with your variale

Answer (score 0):

A `TimeSpan` is for a duration, you should use a `DateTime` (and the [DateTime.ToString(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method) if you want to format the Output in 12-hour-format